# How do I select an element from a Bootstrap dropdown using Python Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, bootstrap-4, dropdownbox

I have problem to select a Bootstrap `DropDown` using Selenium Python.

My code has no Element ID and Element Name. Usually, we can find it by id or name. So I tried using `find_element_by_xpath`.

I found out that Bootstrap `DropDown` cannot be selected by using Select function.

I have to select a Department field. The Department has value of Finance, Human Resource and Information Technology.

This is my code :

This code is for when I click the Department field:

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Select" class="el-input__inner">
```

This code is for the value of department:

```
<li data-v-3f24b47c="" class="el-select-dropdown__item"> 
<span>Finance</span></li>

<li data-v-3f24b47c="" class="el-select-dropdown__item"><span>Human Resources</span></li>

<li data-v-3f24b47c="" class="el-select-dropdown__item selected"><span>Information Technology</span></li>
```

Kindly advice.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium's [Select](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#filling-in-forms) object is supposed to work with [HTML Select](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) tag, given you don't have any Select tags you need to treat the dropdown placeholders and nested entries as separate objects and access it like:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Select']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Finance']").click()
#etc
```

Demo (assumes https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#single-button-dropdowns page)

```
driver.get('https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",
                      driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='#single-button-dropdowns']"))
driver.find_element_by_id('dropdownMenuButton').click()
```

More information on [locating DOM elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) using XPath and friends:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=40044727)

Comment: What if there is default value in that drop down? Eg: system auto-populate 'Information Technology' as default when user open the page since it trace by user's Department. I tried to use clear(), but got error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS Selectors for it

> > > driver.find_element_by_css_selector

Comment: Thanks a for helping!